# Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact Error while deploying on jenkins

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, java-8, pom.xml

This my pom.xml and the errors I get are:

Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bom:pom:0.77.0-alpha from/to central (http://myrepo.maven.apache.org/maven2): /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/google-cloud-bom/0.77.0-alpha/google-cloud-bom-0.77.0-alpha.pom.part.lock (No such file or directory) @ org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:1.1.1.RELEASE, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies/1.1.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies-1.1.1.RELEASE.pom, line 163, column 16

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-service</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>simple-service</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!--                        <goals>-->
                        <!--                            <goal>repackage</goal>-->
                        <!--                        </goals>-->

                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Trying to deploy the project on jenkins but getting error

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for logs.